# Delete tags [tensorflow2] and [tensorflow2.x]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

There is already a tag `tensorflow2.0` which has the highest usage

```
[tensorflow2.0] 3569
[tensorflow2.x]  175
[tensorflow2]     20
```

The other two are probably not necessary.

Comment: I think it can be added as synonyms for the main tag. No need for deletion

Comment: @VadimKotov unfortunately, while we have high scores on the main tag `tensorflow` we don't have a score of at least 5 on the specific tag `tensorflow2.0` to be able to suggest synonymes as you suggest. What should be done in this situation?

Comment: @patapouf_ai You can retag this as a synonym request (and also change title), and then the community and moderators can act accordingly.

Comment: @VadimKotov thanks. I did it.

Comment: I don't want to change the title because it is OP's question and so I don't feel I have to right to change OP's intention. But I retagged.

Answer (score 7):

I vote for merging [tensorflow2.0] into [tensorflow2.x].

- [tensorflow2.x] is clearly more general.
- It doesn't really make sense to have a tag for a subversion.
- In practice, currently the tag [tensorflow2.0] is being used to mean tensorflow2.x, so the merge would make it reflect reality more, see this question for an example:
  [How can i use the data augmentation in Tensorflow 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104171/how-can-i-use-the-data-augmentation-in-tensorflow-2)

And then to have [tensorflow2] be a synonyme of [tensorflow2.x].

Comment: It also fits the pattern of other version tags like [tag:python-3.x] for example.

Comment: I think that makes sense and it's probably the best solution. I don't know if we can rename it to `tensorflow-2.x` as well? I kind of miss the `-` separator.